# How do I show the side bar (incl. available hard drives) when I open the file explorer Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, filemanager, drive

When I open the file explorer it only shows the home directory. It doesn't show any of my hard drives of computer.

How can I make the file explorer show available hard drives?

[image: screenshot of Nautilus]

Comment: Normally it doesn't show your hard drives. What were you expecting?

Comment: Also it's called Files (or Nautilus), not File Explorer. File Explorer is a Windows 8+ program.

Comment: Actually it is not showing explorer menu

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked, actually new to Linux so ps:

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>F9</kbd> to show/hide the left-hand sidebar.